# Is that possible to make priority C higher than B?

Tags: org-mode

From: https://orgmode.org/manual/Priorities.html

> You can change the range of allowed priorities by setting the
>   variables org-highest-priority, org-lowest-priority, and
>   org-default-priority. For an individual buffer, you may set these
>   values (highest, lowest, default) like this (***please make sure that the
>   highest priority is earlier in the alphabet than the lowest priority***):
>
> #+PRIORITIES: A C B

Pay attention to this:

> (...) please make sure that the highest priority is earlier in the alphabet
>   than the lowest priority

Is not possible to define, for example, the following order: A, C, B and D?

If I use the [org-mode API](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-element-api.html) The priority **A** always has a smaller number than **B**, and **B** than **C** and so on.

I use this matrix:

[image]

Where A is urgent and important. B is important but not urgent. And C is urgent but not important. So, C should be "higher priority" than B because it should be done first.

Is that possible to invert the order of priority letters? A, C, B and D? Or not?

Comment: It has been a few years since I last looked at this, but my recollection is that `org-mode` uses the numeric character code value to determine whether a letter is higher/lower than another letter.  E.g., `(string-to-char "A")`.  If that is still the case, then it would be necessary to comb through all of the applicable functions that rely upon those numeric values and change the way it deals with them.

Comment: You are right. Maybe it's not easy as I thought before. Maybe this could be possible in a future version of Emacs.

Comment: You can try and make a feature request. This limitation feels arbitrary to me.

Comment: How can I do that? Do you know?

Comment: The `org-mode` developers have their own gig and the version included in the Emacs public release is always behind the curve.  This linked page has a section dealing with how to submit feature requests:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contribute.html